# What is wrong with the syntax I've used

Tags: c

Hi can someone please help me with this error. In the partition block it says that Im giving "struct list pivot" an incompatible type. It says I need to add more details to my question so Im just gonna go ahead and write more things just ignore.

```
struct list {
    char first;
    char second;
    char third;
    char fourth;
};

struct list *plist[num];

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    plist[i] = &list[i];
}
```

This is where I partition the list. Isn't partitioning fun

```
int part(struct list **A, int start, int finish) {

    //Error is popping up in this block
    struct list pivot = A[start]->first;
    int i = start;
    int j = finish;
    while(1) {

        while(strcmp(A[i]->first, pivot) < 0) {

            i = i + 1;
        }
        while(strcmp(A[j]->first, pivot) > 0) {

            j = j - 1;
        }
        if(i < j){

            swap(&A[i], &A[j]);

        } else {

            return j;

        }
    }
}
```

heres my sort function.

```
void sort(struct list **A, int start, int finish){
    if(start < finish){
        int p = part(A, start, finish);
        sort(A, start, p);
        sort(A, p + 1, finish);
    }
}
```

heres where I try to print my sorted list but it doesn't work... yet

```
sort(plist, 0, num);

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    printf("%s \n\n", plist[i]->first);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? What is the exact error copy/pasted from your compiler output? You should also include the definition of your list struct.

Comment: Probably type mismatch.

Comment: Could you show us how you've defined `struct list`?

Comment: @frslm It is a proprietary definition.:)

Comment: @Ethan Itovitch  It seems that the data member first Is declared as a character array or a character pointer. So the initialization where the error occurred does not make sense.

Comment: struct list
    {
     char first;
     char second;
     char third;
     char fourth;
    };

Comment: error: initializing 'struct StudentRecord' with an expression
      of incompatible type 'char [15]'
        struct StudentRecord pivot = A[start]->LastNames;
                             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account how the data member `first` is used in the code it follows that it is declared either as a character array or a pointer to character. In any case the initialization in this declaration

```
struct list pivot = A[start]->first;
```

does not make sense because the structure and the character array (or pointer to character) are evidently incompatible types.

It seems you could write instead

```
const char *pivot = A[start]->first;
```

If you want to use a structure object as a pivot then you should write

```
struct list pivot = *A[start];
```

and further in the code use expression `pivot.first` instead of `pivot` as for example

```
while(strcmp(A[i]->first, pivot.first) < 0) {
```

Comment: @EthanItovitch All is written in my answer.

Comment: ohh sorry didn't see that. Thanks for the suggestions.